# WPF Prevent button from taking focus from any other control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, focus

I have an "On screen keypad" with some up/down/left/right/select buttons.

The select button is effectively a click and the arrow keys fire the associated up/down/left/right key.

The problem is that when selecting a combo box, I can't press the down/up buttons to navigate the items in the list. It is because the combo box auto closes when loosing focus. I can see similar problems happening with other controls, so I would like to see if there is a way to do the following.

For certain buttons (up/down/etc), when clicked, fire the click event, but don't take focus from w/e currently has the focus. This would allow the combox dropdown to stay open while pressing up/down to navigate through the items.

I have tried to set Focusable=False on the navigation buttons but the focus is still taken away from the combo box and the dropdown closes.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In winforms is there a property `KeyPreview` in a form, that causes  any key event of child controls to occur first in the containing form. Then you can move your items, and setting `Handled` propert of the `KeyEventArgs` to `true`, to prevent the event from continuing and causing focus changes. Maybe is there a similar concept in wpf windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't happening because of anything your `Buttons` are doing so changing their focus state won't make any difference. `ComboBoxes` close when you click *anywhere* outside of them, including empty space, non-interactive controls, other windows...